# Remove Default icons from title bar in winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

How do I remove the default icons(network, battery, volume)from the right corner of the title bar in Compact Framework/c# ?

Comment: I don't think you could remove those in a form application without some external libraries. It's similar to asking how to remove the system tray of a desktop application. If your purpose is to have full screen application, check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9842/Full-screen-feature-in-NET-Compact-Framework

Answer (score 1):

Those icons are not part of your From or even your application.  Those are akin to the system tray in Windows.  You cannot remove them.  Your only option is to make your form borderless and full screen, which will cover them up, and if you still want a "title bar" effect, then paint one in manually on your Form.